# URL of blog when using index.php as blog and front-page.php as homepage

Tags: blog, frontpage

I am building a theme and I am using front-page.php for an individuall homepage and index.php (or home.php) for the blog.

What is the URL of the blog / how its possible to define the URL of the blog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow instruction for [Creating a Static Front Page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page) in Codex. The URL of your blog posts index will be derived from a page you use for "posts page".

Comment: Working, thx u!